# Get error: Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (2) myvideo3.mp4

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I'm getting an error in Chrome for an offline web app. Google Chrome always fails on the third video, despite the URL being correct *and* clicking on the URL in the Google Dev Tools' error message, opens and plays the video in a new tab. (It's always the third, even if I change the order of the videos)

The manifest has three videos (each 30-40 MB). All three can be viewed in chrome and are listed in the manifest. It shows a message that it's downloaded the first two videos but the third always ends in this message:

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (2) myvideo3.mp4
```

I know the manifest is correct because (as mentioned), clicking on the URL in the error message plays the video in a Chrome tab.

**Since it always fails on the 3rd video despite changing the order in the manifest, I believe it's a limit on app cache size. How do I increase this for my app?** This is a desktop.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
test.php
image.png
videos/myvideo1.mp4
videos/myvideo2.mp4
videos/myvideo3.mp4
```

**EDIT: Some more info:**
When I have three videos listed, it loads two and fails on the thrird. BUT, when I take the third off and only have two listed in the manifest, it fails on the 2nd video! What could cause this? (If I have only one video, then it loads that one and the whole manifest)

Using:
Google Chrome 43 on Desktop (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not just a per-web-app size limit, but also a per-file size limit. From [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?hl=en#!topic/chromium-html5/iT-jTQNSh9Q) (and confirmed by my testing), it's `32mb per file` and `260 MB per web app`.

Not sure how to find out the limit on other browsers as this seems to be undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this API documentation correctly: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage
...

Then it is saying Application Cache is part of Temporary Storage where you cannot ask for more space and you get a maximum of 20% of the pool.

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    }, 
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

This function told me I have 100MB of granted space. So I assume my app has 20MB? How do I know how much each individual file can be?

I don't know about the limits mentioned in the post above, they seem to be referencing an old answer.

Comment: That's different from the Application Cache. Notice the name of the object `webkitTemporaryStorage`, it's temporary storage. You cannot programmatically request storage increases with applciation cache. You can simply include files in a manifest and hope the user gives the OK and that it's under the allowed amount.

Comment: Hmm, then why does the documentation above say: Temporary storage is shared among all web apps running in the browser. It is also shared across all offline APIs, such as **App Cache**, IndexedDB, and File System. However, it does not include web storage APIs like Local Storage and Session Storage, which still has a limit of 5 MB per origin.